# Plot multiple lines in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'd like to plot lines from a 3D data frame, the third dimension being an extra level in the column index. But I can't manage to either wrangle the data in a proper format or call the plot function appropriately. What I'm looking for is a plot where many series are plotted in subplots arranged by the outer column index. Let me illustrate with some random data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_points_per_series = 6
n_series_per_feature = 5
n_features = 4

shape = (n_points_per_series, n_features, n_series_per_feature)
data = np.random.randn(*shape).reshape(n_points_per_series, -1)
points = range(n_points_per_series)
features = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(n_features)]
series = [f'S{i}' for i in range(n_series_per_feature)]
index = pd.Index(points, name='point')
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((features, series)).rename(['feature', 'series'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

So for this particular data frame, 4 subplots (`n_features`) should be generated, each containing 5 (`n_series_per_feature`) series with 6 data points. Since the method plots lines in the index direction and subplots can be generated for each column, I tried some variations:

```
data.plot()
data.plot(subplots=True)
data.stack().plot()
data.stack().plot(subplots=True)
```

None of them work. Either too many lines are generated with no subplots, a subplot is made for each line separately or after stacking values along the index are joined to one long series. And I think the `x` and `y` arguments are not usable here, since converting the index to a column and using it in `x` just produces a long line jumping all over the place:

```
data.stack().reset_index().set_index('series').plot(x='point', y=features)
```

In my experience this sort of stuff should be pretty straight forward in Pandas, but I'm at a loss. How could this subplot arrangement be achieved? If not a single function call, are there any more convenient ways than generating subplots in matplotlib and indexing the series for plotting manually?

Comment: exactly what sort of layout are you looking for?

Comment: No. What is your expected plot layout for your example dataframe? And N x M grid of Axes with P series in each? What are N, M, and P?

Comment: According to its docstring `DataFrame.plot` has a `layout` parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with using `seaborn`, it can be used to produce subplots from a data frame column, onto which plots with other columns can then be mapped. With the same setup you had I'd try something along these lines:

```
import seaborn as sns

# Completely stack the data frame
df = data \
    .stack() \
    .stack() \
    .rename("value") \
    .reset_index()

# Create grid and map line plots
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="feature", col_wrap=2, hue="series")
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, x="point", y="value")
g.add_legend()
```

Output:

[image: plot result]

Comment: you can use `g.map`, you don't need `g.map_dataframe`

Comment: @PaulH It seems that the `map_dataframe` is needed. `map` produces a `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'point'`.

Comment: @Felix glad if this was helpful. FYI, I made some more edits to display axis labels and legend.

Comment: If you want to make your plots prettier, you can pass any formatting arguments to `g.map_dataframe()` that would apply to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()`.

Comment: @CanisLupusOccidentalis Very helpful, thanks! Much appreciated. If you don't mind, I edited the answer to condense the information and explain a bit more.